# php - display csv data in tabular format

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I am trying to display the CSV data in my web page with pagination option.This is the code I have so far.

```
<?php

$names = file('demo.csv');
$page = $_GET['page'];

//constructor takes three parameters
//1. array to be paged
//2. number of results per page (optional parameter. Default is 10)
//3. the current page (optional parameter. Default  is 1)
$pagedResults = new Paginated($names, 20, $page);
echo "<ul>";
while($row = $pagedResults->fetchPagedRow()) {
//when $row is false loop terminates
    $row1 = str_replace( ',', "\t", $row );
    echo "<li>{$row1}</li>";
}

echo "</ul>";

//important to set the strategy to be used before a call to fetchPagedNavigation
$pagedResults->setLayout(new DoubleBarLayout());
echo $pagedResults->fetchPagedNavigation();
?>
```

I was having issues with commas getting displayed in my output. However, I have resolved using the str_replace function. Now, I wish to show the data elegantly in a tabular format. I tried the below code that I saw in another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023321/grabbing-contents-of-a-mysql-table-and-display-them-in-a-table-on-web-page-pdo).

```
while($row = $pagedResults->fetchPagedRow()) {
//when $row is false loop terminates
    <table>
    <tr>
    $row1 = str_replace( ',', "\t", $row );
    <td><?php echo "<li>{$row1}</li>";?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
}

echo "</ul>";
```

However, I am not getting output in my screen. Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: You are not outputing correctly, you have html code in your php code that is not escaped. Also get rid of the LI and UL

Comment: What if there is a comma somewhere in the *data* of the CSV cells? Simple splitting and replacing is not going to help in CSV, you'll have to parse. Also, it breaks horribly when using other locales (Dutch Excel for example uses `;` to separate fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$names = file('demo.csv');
$page = $_GET['page'];

//constructor takes three parameters
//1. array to be paged
//2. number of results per page (optional parameter. Default is 10)
//3. the current page (optional parameter. Default  is 1)
$pagedResults = new Paginated($names, 20, $page);

echo "<table border=\"1\">";
//use the following line to manually display column names, 
//if they're not in the 1st row of the CSV file
echo "<tr><td>Column 1 name</td><td>Column 2 name</td><td>Column 3 name</td></tr>";
while($row = $pagedResults->fetchPagedRow()) {
//when $row is false loop terminates
    echo "<tr><td>";
    $row1 = str_replace( ',', "</td><td>", $row );
    echo $row1;
    echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

//important to set the strategy to be used before a call to fetchPagedNavigation
$pagedResults->setLayout(new DoubleBarLayout());
echo $pagedResults->fetchPagedNavigation();
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the update. I need to display the header in all the pages. Also, I am not getting the lines like how we have in excel. Can you guide me in the right direction regarding the same? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing HTML and PHP a little to loosely. Fix like this:

```
while($row = $pagedResults->fetchPagedRow()) {
//when $row is false loop terminates
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    $row1 = str_replace( ',', "\t", $row );
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<li>{$row1}</li>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}

echo "</ul>";
```

or like this:

```
while($row = $pagedResults->fetchPagedRow()) {
//when $row is false loop terminates
?>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <?php $row1 = str_replace( ',', "\t", $row ); ?>
    <td><?php echo "<li>{$row1}</li>";?></td>
    </tr>
    </table><?php
}

echo "</ul>";
```

The first one obviously having the preference, as it as much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Your tables are not placed correctly in the loop.

Please refer the following code:

```
<table><?php
while($row = $pagedResults->fetchPagedRow()) {
//when $row is false loop terminates

?>
<tr>
  <?php  
    $row1 = str_replace( ',', "\t", $row );
        ?>
    <td><?php echo $row1;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php   
}

?></table>
```